# Организация хранения данных веб-сервиса на Google Drive

Tags: java, spring, архитектура, google-drive, интеграция

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно красиво/нормально решить такую задачу:

Есть веб-приложение, данные пользователя в котором нужно хранить на стороне пользователя ( в его личном google drive )
Приложение по OAuth получает токен от гугла, который позволяет ему заливать/скачивать данные из драйва пользователя.
Т.е. все апи, которое есть у гугла - положить файл, скачать файл, создавать папки.
Как удобнее всего организовать хранение и работу с данными ( данные организованы в таблицах, по сути, наиболее подходящий формат для данных - реляционная бд )?
У веб приложения есть REST API, которое оперирует данными пользователя ( при запросе на endpoint приложение должно вытягивать/загружать данные на драйв пользователя )

Были мысли использовать какую-то встроенную СУБД ( типа sqlite ) и просто загружать на драйв пользователя файлик с БД. Но получается, что при каждом запросе от пользователя
файлик нужно скачивать с драйва, открывать/изменять и потом целиком отправлять обратно на драйв. Как-то не звучит не очень - очень много одинаковых данных гоняются туда-сюда.

P.S.  веб-приложение написано на Spring